# django csrf_token inside html in python file

Tags: django, django-csrf

In my models.py I have a helper function which passes some html into a list. I then use that list in views.py. I have been getting a CSRF verification failed, error. Relevant code in models.py below

```
f = """<form action="/solutions/" method="post"> 
<input type="submit"> </form>"""
```

I have tried many things to correct the error including the code below

```
f = """<form action="/solutions/" method="post"> 
{j}
<input type="submit"> </form>""".format(j=django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request))
```

When I do this however I get a 'function' object has no attribute 'META'error. Inside my templates I use {% csrf_token %} but I haven't had success using this inside my helper function.

I have tried doing something like the code below. But have not got it to work either

```
f = """<form action="/solutions/" method="post"> 
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit"> </form>"""
```

Comment: `I have a helper function with passes some html into a list. I then use that list in views.py.` - that's the problem. Stop building templates like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need do add it as a hidden input `<input name="csrfToken" value="token_value" type="hidden">`

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/) do a good job explaining how to get the token value.

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing this right, but its not working for me. I have  <input name="csrfToken" value="token_value" type="hidden"> 
<input type="submit">, inside my form tags. Is that what your suggesting ?

Comment: Are you storing the csrf token into a variable called token_value? You should be able to do something like value"{% .csrf_token %}". Why not just use a form like normal and submit it to the view? I am not following why you are storing it into a variable